# Mongoose - save object with objectid

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here I have two schema:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
   _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   name: String,
   job: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Job',
   }
});

var jobSchema = Schema({
   _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   title: String,
});

var Job = mongoose.model('Job', jobSchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Suppose Job has some records:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b46d41e04cfc922949dcfda"),
    "Title": "Teacher"
}, ...]
```

When I have some person objects to insert:

```
[{
     name: 'Peter',
     job: 'Teacher'
}, ...]
```

Do I need to find the Job's `_id` and convert the `job` field to `ObjectId` type before each save? e.g.

```
Job.findOne({title: p.job}, (j) => {
    Person.save({name: p.name, job: j._id}).exec(()=>{
         // it's ok!
    )}
})
```

Or I can use the middleware or populate function to make it easy? Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

While saving your person , you are needing a job for it.
So this is how you can proceed for the same:

1. Either create a new job / find an existing job.
2. Assign the found job's objects _id field to your new Person and save the same.

Eg.code

```
let person = new Person({
   name : 'TszHin'
});
Job.findOne({ title : 'Abc'})
.then(function(job){
  person.job = job._id;
  person.save();
});
```

Comment: While this is a good answer for some use cases it does not answer the question.  This assumes a lookup record exists.  What if the lookup record does not exist, but you still want to insert the record having a specific ObjectId?  Surely you must be able to hardcode an ObjectId somehow, right?